# Pandas: why do I get different format number under conditions?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe `df` that contains `nan` and strings as `_MISSING`. I want to set the values `nan` and `_MISSING` equal to `-1`.

```
df   A       B
0    4   _MISSING
1   NaN    hello
2    3      tom
3   NaN  _MISSING
```

this is what I am doing:

```
df.ix[df.A.isnull(), 'A'] = -1
df.ix[df.B == '_MISSING', 'B'] = -1
```

this the result

```
df   A       B
0    4      -1
1  -1.0    hello
2    3     tom
3  -1.0     -1
```

where

```
type(df.A[0])
numpy.float64

type(df.B[0])
int
```

Comment: if you're using `read_csv` to create your DataFrame, you can pass the argument 
 " na_values=['_MISSING'] ". Then just use df.fillna(-1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can replace selected values in `B` with `np.nan`, then use [`pd.DataFrame.fillna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html):

```
import numpy as np

df.loc[df['B'] == '_MISSING', 'B'] = np.nan
df = df.fillna(-1)

print(df)

   df    A      B
0   0  4.0     -1
1   1 -1.0  hello
2   2  3.0    tom
3   3 -1.0     -1
```

Answer (score 0):

Pandas casts any integer columns with `NaN` to float.

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,np.nan], 'b':['_MISSING', 'HELLO','World']})
>>> df.ix[df.a.isnull(), 'a'] = -1
>>> type(df.a[0])
<class 'numpy.float64'>
```

whereas, if you replace a value in a non-numeric column, such as

```
>>> df.ix[df.b == '_MISSING', 'b'] = -1
>>> type(df.b[0])
<class 'int'>
```

Pandas converts it to int and if you replace it with a float, do it explicitly, `-1.0`.

```
>>> df.ix[df.b == '_MISSING', 'b'] = -1.0
>>> type(df.b[0])
<class 'float'>
```

Comment: Are you *sure* about that last part (conversion of float to int)? I suspect that you're just picking up the `-1` that you put there in the previous step.

Comment: @MarkDickinson Ah! I executed `df.ix[df.b == '_MISSING', 'b'] = -1.0` just after it, which obviously did not work. Thanks